# Error: Copying of type struct QueueTesting.seller memory[] memory to storage not yet supported

Tags: solidity-0.8.x

I am trying to implement a queue in solidity using arrays. But I keep getting this error. Is there any other way to store array of type struct from memory to storage?

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

contract QueueTesting {
    //implement an arrray to represent as queue
    struct seller {
        address account;
        uint256 amount;
        uint256 remaining;
        uint256 timestamp;
    }

    seller[] private queue;

    modifier isQueueEmpty(){
        require(queue.length != 0, "Queue is empty!");
        _;
    }

    function return_seller_account() internal view returns (address) {
        return queue[0].account;
    }

    function return_seller_amount() internal view returns (uint256) {
        return queue[0].remaining;
    }

    function update_seller(uint256 amount) internal {
        queue[0].amount = amount;
    }

    function enqueue(address account, uint256 amount, uint256 date) internal {
        queue.push(seller(account, amount, 0,date));
    }
    
    function dequeue() internal isQueueEmpty returns (address, uint256, uint256) {
        
        seller[] memory _queue = queue;
        seller memory new_seller = _queue[0];

        if(_queue.length == 1){
            queue.pop();
        }
        else{
            for(uint i = 0; i < _queue.length-1; i++){
                _queue[i] = _queue[i+1];
            }

            queue = _queue;
            queue.pop();
        }

        return (new_seller.account, new_seller.amount, new_seller.timestamp);
    }

    function cancel_order(address account, uint256 amount) internal {
        seller[] memory _queue = queue;

        uint256 remainder = amount;
        uint i = _queue.length;


        while(remainder > 0){
            if(_queue[i].account == account){
                if(_queue[i].remaining >= remainder){
                    _queue[i].remaining -= remainder;
                    remainder = 0;
                }
                else{
                    _queue[i].remaining = 0;
                    remainder -= _queue[i].remaining;
                }
            }
        }
        
        queue = _queue;

    }
}
```

Comment: good stuff. I'm not seeing any compile errors in remix. how does one recreate the error?

Comment: I get this error while compiling on my local machine using Brownie package. It's in the line "queue = _queue" in both the dequeue and cancel order functions.

Comment: You can also get this error if you change the visibility from internal to public in dequeue and cancel order functions.